# Insert letter or number with crunch -t flag

Tags: linux, aircrack-ng, crunch

I'm trying to use `crunch` and `aircrack-ng` to recover my own WiFi password, since I thought it'd be an interesting thing to try and see if it works. However, I've run into a problem.
Theoretically, f my WiFi password were `everythingismine`, but some letters were switched out for numbers (eg. `3verything1smin3`), but I don't know which ones, I'm not sure how to say that something is a letter OR a number using the `-t` flag in `crunch`.

I tried use `crunch 16 16 evrythingsm13 -t %v%ryth%ng%sm%n%`, but that will only replace it with numbers, and of course using `@` instead of `%` will have a similar problem. Is there some character/alternative way to say to use numbers or letters?

Comment: No time for a full answer now, sorry; but please see [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1465491/432690), it may be enough. If it is and you manage to solve your problem then feel free to answer your own question without waiting for my answer to appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Kamil Maciorowski for [his answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1465287/crunch-d-option-with-simple-aa-charset/1465491#1465491).
When you use the character sets in `crunch`, it doesn't actually check if they're lowercase, uppercase, etc. It just checks which group it's in.
For example, if you have `a4 e3` as your character set, you can have the `-t` field `-t @w,som,`, and it would fill the `@`'s with characters from the first group (`a` or `4`), the `,`'s with characters from the second group (`e` or `3`), and so on.

So, I could use the command `crunch 16 16 e3 i1 -t @v@ryth,ng,smin@` to find out what the password is.