# How to generate a Password Dictionary by Regex?

Tags: passwords, regex

I forgot the password I used to encrypt a file, but I know the pattern of the word I used as password. I try to bruteforce the file, but it will take thousands of years to be decrypted, so the easy way I found is to use a password dictionary of words matching the text pattern I used to encrypt the file.

Do you know if there's a way to generate a password dictionary of words following a defined pattern?

Edit : for example, if I use a password matching this following pattern in regex : In regex, it will be like `(A|a)lice(\d)?@(B|b)ob(\d)?` , is there a way to generate a dictionary composed by all the words matching this regex pattern ?

Comment: By "words" you mean existing meaningful words? or "words" as general strings matching a pattern like CapitalLetter+Symbol+5xLowercase+Digit? If the latter then research [`crunch`](https://superuser.com/a/1465491/432690).

Comment: In regex, it will be like (A|a)lice(\d)?@(B|b)ob(\d)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know how to use Python, there is a module named [Exrex](https://github.com/asciimoo/exrex).
Then you just can generate a dict.txt file by using the module like this after installing it :

```
exrex (A|a)lice(\d)?@(B|b)ob(\d)? -o dict.txt
```

**WARNING :** Be careful about the pattern you want to use. There is a case that a large file size may be generated depend on the pattern range match.

See more about Exrex [here](https://github.com/asciimoo/exrex#exrex)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> (A|a)lice(\d)?@(B|b)ob(\d)?
> ```

A simple POSIX shell script can generate matching strings. The solution may not be optimal, it doesn't scale very well; but it's [simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and easily customizable.

```
#!/bin/sh

for x1 in A a
do
   for x2 in '' 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
   do
      for x3 in B b
      do
         for x4 in '' 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
         do
            printf '%slice%s@%sob%s\n' "$x1" "$x2" "$x3" "$x4"
         done
      done
   done
done
```

Comment: I'll try this :)

Comment: It works great, thank you very much :)